# How can I join the ArangoDB community of developers?

Tags: arangodb

I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this question but honestly there doesn't seem to be a right forum. Can someone tell me who to contact if I would like to join the ArangoDB community and contribute?

Thank you,
Andrew

Comment: Based on their [page](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb), I think their [Slack](https://slack.arangodb.com/) may be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Start by getting familiar with the ArangoDB presence on GitHub at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb

They have a number of ways to get in touch with the ArangoDB community as well as contribute to the project.

Also check the ArangoDB web site at https://arangodb.com/community/

Did you find these sites while Googling how to get involved?

I'm interested if they didn't appear in your search results.